# Can LTSpice used in command line on MacOS?

Tags: ltspice, ngspice

Can LTSpice used in the terminal by a command line? 
Is there any example there ? I only saw examples in Windows OS

How would simulating a circuit file using LTSpice using terminal in MacOS? (like using NGSpice in command line)

Comment: It looks like you answered your main question already for Windows OS. I'd suggest adding "on MacOS" to your title

Comment: Oh yes, İ just edited the title, thanks

Comment: Does [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294310/start-a-ltspice-simulation-using-code-in-macos/338535) answer your question?

Comment: I tried it, but it will open the LTSpice app window, what I need is to execute it in the background without actually opening in

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your terminal .cir file can also be stimulated.

```
<Path\of\the\program>\XVII86.exe -b -Run file_name.asc
```

LTSpice simulation can be executed by batch process using command prompt

**LTSpice Help > Modes of Operation > Command Line Switches**

`-b` will execute `.cir` or `.asc` without opening LTSpice